# VB NET. How fire an event when other event is fired?

Tags: vb.net, events, user-controls, event-handling

Best regards. I'm here, developing in VisualBasic.Net again.

I create a UserControl who can create buttons in execution time and I need a way to execute a function in the Form where I use the UserControl every time I click one of the buttons.

I was thinking handdle my function to the UserControl's Click event and fire this when I click in the buttons but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: If I understood correctly you can dynamically perform click event of `usercontrol` in the button's click event by just calling `usercontrolname_PerformClick()`

Comment: I can't since I don't know from inside of the UserControl which function(s) in the Form (or Forms because I can Use this UserControl everywhere) is going to be fired.

Comment: Sorry i've overlooked the part where you add the buttons dynamically... updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Event:

```
Public Class DemoUserControl

    Private Sub btnFiresClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFiresClick.Click
        RaiseEvent CustomClick() 'Fire the event
    End Sub

    Public Event CustomClick()
End Class
```

And handle it in the Form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub DemoUserControl1_CustomClick() Handles DemoUserControl1.CustomClick
        ' your code
    End Sub

End Class
```

Dynamically:

```
Private Sub DemoUserControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim newButton As New Button
    AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf btnFiresClick_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(newButton)

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this way to work with events. You've opened me a new world.  I'm going to try it tomorrow because now is late.

Comment: I'd rename the eventhandler to a a more calling name... all this does is relay the event occurance... you can add data to the event too so the host form gets info about what actually happend.